# How to replace this code with a non obsolete code in a SonarQube (5.1.x) language plugin?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

[word of caution: names mangled; this is closed source but I show as much code as I possibly can to highlight the logic. Sorry for that.]

I asked this question on the SonarQube development mailing list but to no avail so far...

Here is the code (names somewhat mangled):

```
public final class MyProfile
    extends ProfileDefinition
{
    // RuleFinder is DEPRECATED
    private final RuleFinder finder;

    public MyProfile(final RuleFinder finder)
    {
        this.finder = finder;
    }

    @Override
    public RulesProfile createProfile(final ValidationMessages validation)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final List<Class> checks = MyChecks.all();

        return new AnnotationBasedProfileBuilder(finder).build(
            PluginConstants.REPOSITORY_KEY,
            PluginConstants.DEFAULT_QUALITY_PROFILE,
            PluginConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY,
            checks,
            validation
        );
    }
}
```

This code is registered as a component of the SonarQube plugin (using SonarPlugin#getExtensions()); its effect is to create a quality profile for the language identified by `PluginConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY` with name `PluginConstants.DEFAULT_QUALITY_PROFILE` for all rules defined in `PluginConstants.REPOSITORY_KEY`.

And this is where the trouble starts.

First of all, `MyChecks.all()`: `MyChecks` is this:

```
public final class MyChecks
{
    private static final List<Class<? extends MyCheck>> NOARG_CHECKS;
    private static final List<Class<? extends MyCheck>> ARG_CHECKS;

    static {
        List<Class<? extends MyCheck>> list;

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        // add implementations of MyCheck here

        NOARG_CHECKS = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        // add other implementations of MyCheck here, but with IOC dependecies

        ARG_CHECKS = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    private MyChecks()
    {
        throw new Error("nice try!");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List<Class> all()
    {
        final List<Class> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(NOARG_CHECKS);
        list.addAll(ARG_CHECKS);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "ReturnOfCollectionOrArrayField", "rawtypes" })
    public static Collection noargChecks()
    {
        return NOARG_CHECKS;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static Collection argChecks(final Settings settings)
    {
        final List<MyCheck> list = new ArrayList<>();

        // add here checks whose constructors depend on "settings"

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
}
```

No relationship to any `PluginConstants.*` so far, right? Well, here it comes...

I also have this:

```
public final class MyRulesDefinition
    implements RulesDefinition
{
    @Override
    public void define(final Context context)
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final List<Class> list = MyChecks.all();

        // SonarConstans.DEFAULT_RULE_REPOSITORY is "SonarQube";
        // it is not used in _any other place_ than here
        final NewRepository repo = context.createRepository(
            PluginConstants.REPOSITORY_KEY,
            PluginConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY
        ).setName(SonarConstants.DEFAULT_RULE_REPOSITORY);

        AnnotationBasedRulesDefinition.load(repo, PluginConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY,
            list);

        repo.done();
    }
}
```

We find back both `REPOSITORY_KEY` and `LANGUAGE_KEY` here.

If this were all there was to it, that would be no fun, right? Well let's continue!

Now we arrive to the language sensor:

```
public final class MySquidSensor
    implements Sensor
{
    // HERE
    private final Checks<MyCheck> checks;

    /*
     * Yes, unfortunately, Sonar has "taken over" a name used by the JDK here.
     */
    private final org.sonar.api.batch.fs.FileSystem fs;

    private final FilePredicate predicate;
    private final ResourcePerspectives perspectives;
    private final Settings settings;

    public MySquidSensor(final org.sonar.api.batch.fs.FileSystem fs,
        final CheckFactory checkFactory,
        final ResourcePerspectives perspectives,
        final Settings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.fs = fs;
        this.perspectives = perspectives;

        predicate = fs.predicates().hasLanguage(PluginConstants.LANGUAGE_KEY);

        // HERE
        checks = checkFactory.
            <MyCheck>create(PluginConstants.REPOSITORY_KEY)
            .addAnnotatedChecks(MyChecks.noargChecks())
            .addAnnotatedChecks(MyChecks.argChecks(settings));
    }

    // some other, irrelevant code
}
```

And here, we find `REPOSITORY_KEY` again. And do note the call to both the `.noArgChecks()` and `.argChecks()` methods of `MyChecks`.

---

OK, well, that was a lot of code, but my question is really simple, although the answer may not be: `RuleFinder` is deprecated; how do I transform this code so that I do not use it? Do I need to change my `ProfileDefinition` implementation? If yes, what with? If no, what do I need to change and how?

Comment: A wild guess: Reimplement [`AnnotationBasedProfileBuilder`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr-squid-bridge/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/squidbridge/annotations/AnnotationBasedProfileBuilder.java) with [`Rules`](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/rule/Rules.java) instead of the finder. That's the only place I see it's used.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone getting here via google - according to this post to the developer mailing list (in response to @fge) `RuleFinder` is not currently deprecated for server side components, just batch side ones.

http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-RulesFinder-is-deprecated-but-what-replaces-it-td5035167.html

So code using `RuleFinder` is not obsolete.